# Something preventing redirect from being executed

Tags: rules, redirection, tokens

I'm using d7.

I've a flag "I have a solution" attached to a "problem" content type
When an user flags it a rule is fired.

Actions are:
1 - create a new "solution" content, name it "justcreated-solution"
2 - save it
3 - add a list of variables to collect relations endopoints
4 - add the first "problem" endpoint
5 - add the seconf "solution" endpoint
6 - create the relation
7 - redirect to the [justcreated-solution:edit-url]

the bad thing is that redirect in 7 is NOT working!

*if I add a 6.1 step that prints a system message with [justcreated-solution:edit-url], I realize the url is correct, nonetheless the redirect never happens*

any suggestion?
many thanks in advance

Angelo

P.S: an absolute web address redirect (http://example.com/whatever) that works in another simple rule created for testing, in this rule doesn't work at all!

Comment: nobody willing to help? or am I unclear?